# How can I completely transfer sharepoint site from one server to other?

Tags: sharepoint

What is the easiest way to transfer a Sharepoint site along with workflows and people and groups content and all lists contents from one server to another?

I tried saving site as template stp with include all content, but the workflows are not working anymore and the people and groups are also not replicated on the new server.

Comment: You should really define "server" in order to get an accurate answer to this question. Do you mean to a new farm? A new web application? A new site collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stsadm -o backup -url http://oldportal -filename C:\oldportal.dat

take the .dat to the new server, create a new WebApplication with a Blank Site Collection

stsadm -o restore -url http://newportal -filename C:\oldportal.dat -overwrite

Custom Features and Solutions won't get transfered, but the items you mentioned (workflows, people, groups) will all be transfered.

Comment: (This is only supported since Service Pack 2)

Comment: I thought workflows won't get transferred, as stated in http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc706866.aspx
"You cannot restore workflow, alerts, features, solutions, or Recycle-Bin state by using the import operation."

Comment: the Backup / Restore features are different from Import / Export

Answer (score 2):

Workflows definitions A restore of a Site(s) using SharePoint’s `STSADM –o import` command will bring across the definition and association data of all Workflows within the Site(s). There are two additional administrative steps that must be completed before and after the export/import steps, these are:

1. Run the command `NWAdmin –o preparesiteforexport`, before executing `STSADM –o export` on your Site(s).
2. Run the command `NWAdmin –o fixsiteafterimport`, after executing `STSADM –o import` on your Site(s).

Performing the above steps will ensure referential integrity of the Workflow to all SharePoint objects within the workflow definition. Specifically, the STSADM import process generates new GUIDs for all SharePoint objects: Sites, Webs, Lists, and ListItems.

In order to remap the imported workflows to the newly generated GUIDs, we provide the `preparesiteforexport` and the `fixsiteafterimport` to work around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting the site using stsadm.exe -o export.  Use the parameter -includeusersecurity.  Are you moving to a different farm? Different domain?